# Rails list all valid content types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-type

Is there any class in Rails Api that lists all `Content-Type` for `ActionController` ?

**Like HTML, JSON, XML, JS, etc.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Mime::EXTENSION_LOOKUP](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb#L25) has all the available mime types.

Content type `html` would then be retrieved using `Mime::EXTENSION_LOOKUP['html']`:

```
[32] pry(main)> Mime::EXTENSION_LOOKUP["html"].to_s
=> "text/html"
```

Comment: Awesome! `Mime::EXTENSION_LOOKUP.keys` :)

Comment: `Mime::EXTENSION_LOOKUP.values.map(&:to_s).uniq` to see the types themselves.